Why is my wordcloud2 figpath not working?
I am trying to make a wordcloud of the most common words a country's wikipedia in the shape of the country.
wordcloud2(word_freq_df)
This code correctly returns the wordcloud as shown here: 
wordcloud2(word_freq_df, figPath = "united_kingdom.png", size =1)
This code returns only the source image 
No matter what mask I use it seems to have this issue. Is figpath broken?
I tried to use the figpath command and a correct mask to change the shape of the wordcloud. However, it just returns the mask.

I have managed to get it working by getting the package directly from github and saving the wordcloud with saveHTML. However, when I open it it only displays after refreshing a few times. Why is this?

Is this answer helpful?
